# Why is the visual selection represented by these characters: '<,'> ? Can it be parsed?

Tags: visual-mode, history-of

While I can understand the percentage sign <kbd>%</kbd> being chosen to represent the current file, just because you need to choose some character for that, I am curious as to why `'<,'>` is representative of the current visual selection.

1. Why not just use a single character to represent the visual selection?
2. Can these characters be parsed to have a different meaning?
3. is `'<` supposed to mean something like,

   > The **lesser than** value of the **quoted** text ?
4. Are there any other useful variations of `'<,'>` that I should know, say for example, `'>,'<`?

Comment: Yes, it does mean something: it's a range (see `:h :range`) going from line `'<` to line `'>`.  The `'<mumble>`  denotes the mark `<mumble>` (see `:h '`).  And marks `<` and `>` are (surprise!) the first and last lines in a marked region (cf. `:h '<` and `:h '>`).

Comment: `is '< supposed to mean something` you had the right question, you could have asked it to the doc [`:h '<`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#%27<)

Comment: @statox Everything is obvious in hindsight. :)

Comment: @statox That gives half the answer (that it breaks down into `'<` and `'>` as start and end) but the relationship to "marks" (and what exactly marks *are*) isn't immediately obvious.

Comment: @SatoKatsura You're probably right... @IMSoP it's maybe not immediately obvious but the `'<` paragraph is in a chapter called `7. Marks`. Anyway OP get a good answer that's the important point :-)

Answer (score 6):

This is actually *mark* notation. Anytime you go into a visual selection the beginning of the selection is marked with the mark `<`, and the end with the mark `>`. You can also do ex-commands between two arbitrary marks that you place yourself. i.e. `:'a,'bs/foo/bar/`. Vim is just borrowing from the system already in place.

As for what `'>,'<` would mean. Since we now know this is mark notation, we can see that this would give us a backwards range. (I think vim can sometimes operate on backwards ranges, but it's generally not very happy about them.)